# Is there a way to boolean difference curve objects?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves, extrude, svg

I want to avoid converting my objects into meshes. Can I boolean from extruded curve objects? For example, here I am trying to boolean out the interior of the letter "a" from an extruded svg. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Geometry Nodes` modifier (on your extruded *.svg* object) instead of `Boolean` to accomplish that:

[image]

Couple of things to note:

- There's no such thing as a curve with faces. When you use the *Geometry > Extrude* or *Shape > Fill Mode* options of a curve from the *Properties* panel, the result is actually a mesh. What's happening is equivalent to a setup like `Fill Curve` > `Extrude Mesh` in Geometry Nodes, it's just not exposed to neither the user nor to the other modifiers.
- Take care to keep the `Object Info` node in *Relative* mode so your curve/text object's world position is used.
- Unfortunately, the `Mesh Boolean` node in Geometry Nodes operates only in the *Exact* mode of the `Boolean` modifier (instead of *Fast*). Good for more precise results, but also much slower.